Is there fit width text and newLine in compose Text?

Hello, I am developing using Compose and have a question. I want to make the text fill the width completely and then move to the next line, rather than breaking onto a new line before reaching the end. Is there a way to achieve this without using font scaling?

That happens because the word ajkdjflkjeoqiurioq cannot fit in the available width, so Text moves it to the next line.
You can use textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
TextAlign.Justify

Stretch lines of text that end with a soft line break to fill the width of the container.

But this will have varying gaps between words, just like in News Paper.
